# Unable to set values on lightning-record-view-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordviewform

**HTML TEMPLATE**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Custom Search Functionality in LWC" icon-name="standard:account">
        <div if:true={errorMsg} style="margin-left: 3%;">
            <p style="color: red;">{errorMsg}</p>
        </div>

        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="end">
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="10" medium-device-size="8" large-device-size="6" padding="around-small">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <lightning-input type="text" 
                                                 label="Enter Customer Name" name ="cusName"
                                                 onchange={handleCustomerName} ></lightning-input>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="2" medium-device-size="2" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-button label="Search" 
                                  variant="brand" 
                                  onclick={handleSearch}></lightning-button>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout><br/>

        <template if:true={show}>
            <div class="acc-container">
                {recordId}
                <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Client__c">
                    <div class="slds-grid">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <lightning-output-field field-name="Name"></lightning-output-field>
                            <lightning-output-field field-name="Date_of_Birth__c"></lightning-output-field>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <lightning-output-field field-name="Photo__c"></lightning-output-field>
                            <lightning-output-field field-name="Booking_Date__c"></lightning-output-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </lightning-record-view-form>
            </div>
        </template>
       
  
</lightning-card>
```

**js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getDetail from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.getDetail';

export default class ClientDefinition extends LightningElement {
    cusName = '';
    @track show = false;
    @track recordId;

    handleCustomerName(event) {
        this.cusName =  event.target.value;
    }

    handleSearch() {
        if(this.cusName.equals('')) {
            this.errorMsg = 'Please enter customer name to search.';
            return;
        }
 
        getDetail({ clientName: this.cusName})
         
    
       .then(result => {
        this.show = true;
        alert(result);
        this.recordId = result;
       })
    
       .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            alert("FAILURE" + error);
             //this.error = error;
       });
    }
}
```

**Apex controller class**

```
public with sharing class PriceFetch {
   
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getDetail(String clientName) {
       
        String search = '%' + clientName + '%';
       
       List<Client__c> clients = new List<Client__c>();
         clients = [
            SELECT Id, Name, Unit__c, Total_cost__c, Remarks__c, Project__c,Profession__r.Name,Photo__c,PAN__c,Father_Spouse__c,Email_id__c,
            Date_of_Birth__c,Contact_Number__c,Communication_address__c,Booking_Date__c,Booking_Amount__c,Agreement_Date__c,Aadhar_Number__c
            FROM Client__c
            WHERE Name LIKE :search
            LIMIT 1];
            if(clients.size() == 0) {
                 throw new AuraHandledException('exceptionText');
            }
            
           return clients.get(0).Id;   
    }
}
```

Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: are you able to print that recordid in html?

Comment: Hi Sahil, issue resolved now, In my SOQL query Project, Unit were custom look up fields. So I need write like this 'Project__r.Name', 'Unit__r.Name'. That was the mistake

Comment: @AthiraVenugopal please post the fix as an answer and mark it as accepted. Doing so will close the question and help others in the future who may have a similar issue